# elusive jQuery JSON Parser error

Tags: django, json, forms, jquery

I have a an ajax call returning JSON to a loop to populate form fields. The raw data looks fine, but it never makes it though the loop and into the form, and an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" error is thrown at line 1 of the document.

This is the ajax function:

```
$(function() {
$('#id_license' ).blur( function() {
    q = $( '#id_license' ).val();
    $.ajax({
        datatype: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: 'lic='+q,
        url: "/usr/xhr_license_search/?xhr",
        success: function(data)
        { $.each(data, function(field, value){
                  $("#id_"+field).val(value);



        });
            console.log(data);
      }
});
```

});
});

This is the raw JSON returned: 
*(manually anonymized)*

```
{"First_Name":"Jon","Last_Name":"Doe","address":"2 A st.","city":"anthtown","grade":"T5","licNum":"08933","state":"TA","user":1099,"zipCode":09117}
```

I'm using json.dump() in Django to format the response.

Thank you in advance for your incites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem quite a few times before, it's something to do with the return dataType. By using $.get or $.post instead of $.ajax I've been able to solve the problem, so for you:

```
$.post('/usr/xhr_license_search/?xhr', 'lic='+q, function(data){
    $.each(data, function(field, value){
        $("#id_"+field).val(value);
    });
}, 'json');
```

Doing that should give you no error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure JSON will be confused by the leading 0 in the zipCode; that shouldn't parse as a number, according to json.org . Are you sure you didn't intend that to be a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a pair of parentheses around the raw json, which makes it like

```
({"First_Name":"Jon","Last_Name":"Doe","address":"2 A st.","city":"anthtown","grade":"T5","licNum":"08933","state":"TA","user":1099,"zipCode":09117})
```